# Test a boolean Method in Java

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Good afternoon, 
i am having troubles with testing a boolean Method. 
I have my interface (Dao)

```
   public interface UserDao {
public boolean existUser(String email) throws UserException;
}
```

And my method is

```
public boolean existUser(String email) throws UserException {       
        try{
            log.info("Verify exist email " + email);
            Map<String, Object> parametersMap = Maps.newHashMap();
            parametersMap.put("email", email);
            Long count = npTemplate.queryForLong("SELECT count(*) FROM DL_USER WHERE EMAIL = :email", parametersMap);

            if(count > 0){
                return true;
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            String errorMsg = "There was an exception trying obtain user id for " + email + " - ERROR " + e.getMessage();
            UserException uException = new UserException(errorMsg, e);
            throw uException;
        }       
        return false;
    }
```

I would like to test the existUser method.

Comment: why don't you give it a try and let us know what is the trouble you are facing

Comment: Don't `catch (Exception ...`, catch the specific checked exceptions.

Comment: *i am having troubles with testing a boolean Method*. What would those troubles be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a set of test data comprising arguments to the method of which some should yield `true`, some `false`, and others the exception. Call the method with each value in turn and check the actual result with the expected result. Use a database with known content so you know what the expected values should be.

I prefer TestNG for this kind of testing.

Incidentally, the `return false;` should be inside the `try` block with the `return true`. Then you could eliminate the test of a `boolean` to return a `boolean` and simply `return count > 0;`.

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two ways to test this kind of stuff:

a) As Lew already suggested, you could make this an **integration test**, which means you actually connect to the database, query the user, etc. If you want to be 100% sure, you can even create the user during test initialization and remove the user afterwards (for example by wrapping the whole test in a transaction and doing a rollback at the end). This will prevent your tests from depending on a specific database state or clutter the database with test data.

b) You could also make this a **unit test** via **mocking**. For this you would have to mock `npTemplate`, removing the need for an actual database connection. Then you can verify if `npTemplate` was called with the correct parameters. Also you can make it return various numbers to test different situations and even let it throw Exceptions to test that. [Mockito](http://site.mockito.org/) is the to go framework for this kind of stuff, but there are others as well (for example [EasyMock](http://easymock.org/)).

The obvious drawback to solution b) is, that you cannot guarantee that your query is actually correct, which doesn't leave much to test. Still, I personally would write both tests, a unit test **and** a integration test, since the unit test will ensure that the code around your query and the result handling is correct, while the integration test will ensure that your query actually works. (And yes, the integration test will also ensure that the code is correct, but running an integration test often takes far more time, so you can run your unit tests during development all the time and the integration tests only when needed).

And a little P.S., using...

```
return count > 0;
```

...will make your code more concise, since you will not have two different places where a return happens.